# How to hide debugger on view pages in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Mainly I have to hide the debugger on every view pages in cakephp3[image]. Can anybody give me any suggestions regarding this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *config/bootstrap.php* file and find following somewhere:

```
Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
```

Change it to:

```
Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => false]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to Config/app.php file and change

```
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', 1), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)
```

with this

```
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', 0), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)
```